# How to read huge number of CSV files from S3 bucket efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, large-files

I have 750,000 CSV input files in a S3 bucket which needs to be transformed and loaded into an output folder which will also be stored in CSV.

While I have a notebook which reads these many files, executing it takes hours and goes idle. Looking for a solution where I could run this notebook based on certain number of files at a time. Say 1,000 files at one time and then depending on time execution gradually increase the number.

So if my first run reads the first 1,000 files from S3 then, the second run should pick from 1,001st file and so on till it reads the last file.

Individual input file size varies from 50 to 100 kilobytes.

Comment: Sync the files onto your local machine first, with e.g. `aws s3 sync` or `rclone`, and run from there?

Comment: Either way: if you're loading the CSV files sequentially, that will be a bottleneck; you could look into `multiprocessing` to load them in parallel, be it from a local source or S3.